# How to clear text from textarea input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have the following form and I would like to clear any user inputs when I close the form. I do so with the following JQ function, however the textarea elements do not clear in the same manner (`#reply` will only clear using `.val("")`). I do not understand why that is.

```
HTML
<div class="form" id="form">
  <form id="postandreply" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" >
    <div id="textarea">
      <label for="posttopic">Topic</label>
  <textarea id="posttopic" name="posttopic" maxlength="100" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
      <label for="comment">Comment</label>
      <textarea id="comment" name="posttext" maxlength="500" cols="80" rows="6"></textarea>
      <label for="reply">Reply</label>
      <textarea id="reply" name="replytext" maxlength="500" cols="80" rows="6"></textarea>
   </div>

      <input type="text" id="lookup" name="reply-lookup" />
     <input type="submit" id="submit" name="post" value="Post" />

  </form>
</div>

JQ
// -------------------------reset the forms -------------------------   
function reset(formhtml) {

$('#posttopic, #comment, #reply').text(""); //will not clear #reply
$('#lookup, #reply').val("");              //this will clear #reply
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.val()` is the main method to get inputted data. Heres a quote from http://api.jquery.com/val/.

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of  elements, the .val() method returns an array
>   containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns
>   null.

`.text()` does not work as `textarea` is still an input.

Answer (score 2):

From JQuery documentation:

> The *[**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)* method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the *[**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)* method. To get the value of a script element, use the *.html()* method.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('#form')[0].reset(); // use the id of the form
```

Comment: @user2232681 then what are you waiting for.. mark this as the correct answer.. lol.. glad i could help :)